# Curved Text in React (SVG textPath not working)

Tags: javascript, svg, reactjs

I am looking to have an arc-shaped title at the top of my React page. I am looking to stay away from JQuery, so I am using SVG.

This is the code I wrote, which works outside of react:

```
<svg width='100%'>
    <defs>
        <path id="bigArc" d="m0,170 a800,800 0 0 1 800,0"/>
    </defs>
    <text x="200" fill='#003399' style="font-size: 80px;">
        <textPath xlink:href="#bigArc" >
            Come on in...
        </textPath>
    </text>
</svg>
```

This is my non-working code inside React return ():

```
<svg width='500px'>
    <defs>
        <path id='bigArc' d='m0,170 a800,800 0 0 1 800,0'/>
    </defs>
    <text x='200' fill='#003399' style={{ fontSize: 80 }} >
        <textPath xlinkHref='#bigArc' >
            Come on in...
        </textPath>
    </text>
</svg>
```

At the moment, my React page *does* display the "Come on in..." text, but it is **not** curved. It seems like React is struggling to interpret `<textPath>`.

I am not getting any console errors, and my code does build, but the text does not follow the arc path.

I am using ES6, react 0.14.2 and react-dom ^0.14.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For people reading this now, ReactJS has full SVG support as of version 15.
So the `<textPath>`element should now work as expected.

For details read the [React v15.0 release notes](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/04/07/react-v15.html).

Answer (score 1):

`textPath` is currently not supported so you'd have to resort to using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

```
let textPath = `<textPath xlink:href="#bigArc">Come on in...</textPath>`;
<text dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: textPath }}></text>;
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/woLL3gke/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am just wondering whether there are any security concerns with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, as this is a production app. Do you think this would be a potential XSS risk, or not in this case?

Comment: Yes, it's a huge security risk using this especially if you're doing user input in your `textPath` variable, other than that, if this is the only thing you're doing and you've sanitized it and checked it you should be fine. http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html

Answer (score 1):

so the problem is react not having full svg support, which is something still being worked on.

Maybe something like this would help: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1657#issuecomment-70786561

I havent worked with react but thats what I could gather. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, Zee. That could work, but still a bit concerned about XSS. I may need to go down the jQuery avenue…